# Jquery-ui append template on drop and make appended templates child as droppable(nested)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-append

How to Append template while dropping and dropped template's child as droppable(nested).

```
$template=$("<div class="static">box1</div><div class="droppable-box-nested">box2</div>");
```

Need to append above code to my below fiddle while dropping and box2 is droppable.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raj_cbe/vwyd9cz1/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks like you resolved your previous question that was similar. I do not see where `$template` is used ion your fiddle. Please clarify what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues in your `$template`, it should be something like:

```
var $template = $("<div class='static'>Box 1</div><div class='droppable-box-nested'>Box 2</div>");
```

The use of `"` breaks out of your string and you should use `'`.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vwyd9cz1/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  var $template = $("<div class='static'>Box 1</div><div class='droppable-box-nested'>Box 2</div>");

  $('.dragItem').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: "#column2,#column2 div"
  });

  $('.dragItem').sortable({
    containment: "parent"
  });

  $('#column2').sortable({
    placeholder: "highlight"
  });

  $('#column2').droppable({
    accept: '.dragItem',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      var droppable = $(this);
      var drag = $('#column2').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({});
      drag.appendTo(column2);
      $template.insertAfter(drag);
      drag.sortable({
        placeholder: "highlight"
      });
      drag.droppable({
        accept: ".dragItem",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var draggable = ui.draggable;
          var droppable = $(this);
          var drag = $('#column2').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({});
        }
      })
      drag.css({
        width: '',
        height: ''
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/raj_cbe/sbjwoaos/3/    how to make child2 as also droppable?i need both parent and child as droppable the same content when dropped on particular target(nested n number of times)?